# echo writes a variable to file with inverted commas

Tags: bash, input, echo

script code:

```
    echo "Command?"
    read command
```

for example command = echo "Hello world"

```
    $command > text.txt
    cat text.txt
```

The output is "Hello world" (with inverted commas), but I need the same output as 
gives simple

```
    echo "Hello world" > text.txt
```

i.e. Hello world. How can I get it?
Please keep in mind that $command can take any values, must execute in the current bash and the output saved in file.

Comment: "USE MORE QUOTES!" They are vital. Also, learn the difference between ' and " and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you want to do. is it `echo "$command" > text.txt` ?

Comment: to be safer: can't you propose instead a list of available commands, and have the user input the number of that command? That way you don't accept "everything" (if accepting everything, clever/evil users can do almost everything with your script. VERY VERY difficult to sanitize every possible inputs)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
eval "$command" > text.txt
```

But be careful - what if someone enters `rm -rf /`?

Comment: thanks choroba! if someone enters rm -rf / it will be his problem :D I need to write a code that takes commands from a shell, stores them like variable, executes, and saves stdout or stderr

Answer (score 0):

If you need to `eval` a command and then save `STDOUT` or `STDERR` :

For `STDOUT` :

```
eval "$command" > text.txt
```

And for `STDERR` :

```
eval "$command" 2> text.txt
```

But, take care,  `eval` is a common misspelling of 'evil'. If `eval` is the answer, surely you are asking the wrong question. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Last but not least, "USE MORE QUOTES!" They are vital. Also, learn the difference between ' and " and `. See mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: I just found that if $command=clear and I use

       eval "$command" > text.txt

the current bash window will not be cleaned =(

Comment: @Olga : it is because "clear" works by sending to STDOUT the necessary stuff to clear that stdout. If you redirect STDOUT to "text.txt", those commands are sent to "text.txt" and no longer to the original STDOUT (ie, the terminal). If you want to BOTH send to the original STDOUT and to "file.txt" : use:  `command | tee file.txt`